# Draw a doughnut in Google Maps JavaScript API (highlight the outside of inner circle and the inside of outer circle)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to draw a doughnut with Google Maps JavaScript API?
For highlighting the outside of inner circle and the inside of outer circle.

[image: doughnut]

My idea is to put the inner circle before the outer.
The problem is it cannot be loaded when setting the fillOpacity of the inner circle.

```
var citymap = {};
citymap['innerCircle'] = {
      center: amsterdam,
      radius: 3146.2245383489244,
      //opacity = 0.0 // bug here
    };
citymap['outerCircle'] = {
      center: amsterdam,
      radius: 7021.113634532091,
      opacity: 0.35};    
for (var city in citymap) {
var populationOptions = {
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#FF0000',                              
  fillOpacity: citymap[city].opacity,    
  map: map,
  center: citymap[city].center,
  radius: citymap[city].radius
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in google maps  you can draw polygon with  hole the first polygon is the outer shape e the other are the inner shape 
see this stackoverflow for examples [ring example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397874/draw-ring-not-circle-in-google-maps-api)